# Having Difficulty understand Alloc and init

Tags: objective-c

I am learning about the alloc and init but I don't understand what its supposed to mean. they gave example of

```
NSString *emptyString = [[NSString alloc] init];
NSArray *emptyArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
NSDictionary *emptyDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
```

And i got no clue what it would even be used for.

---

Next i had to use the stringWithString and did this. no clue whats going on here too. Can someone help me but explain it in a understandable/easy matter. thank you

```
NSString *firstName = @"Daniel";
NSString *copy = [[NSString alloc] stringWithString:firstName];
NSLog(@"%@ is a copy of %@", copy, firstName);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Creating the empty array and dictionary is a bit strange; normally you'd only do that with their mutable versions. I suppose the empty string could be used for comparisons with other string objects, but even then, using `@""` seems like it would be easier to read.

   `alloc` is a class method that allocates space for an object of the appropriate class. `init` is an instance method that initializes that new instance so that it can behave correctly as an object of that class.
2. This use of `stringWithString` is incorrect; you shouldn't be using it with `alloc`. Something like:

   ```
   NSString *copy = [firstName copy];
   ```

   would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

**First Point:**

If you are familiar with C++ code, when you create an object, basically you create a new instance of that class as follows:

```
ClassA object1= new ClassA();
```

`new` is nothing but `alloc+init` in the objective-C

```
ClassA *object1 = [[ClassA alloc] init];
```

**Second Point:**

```
[NSString stringWithString:@"some string"]
```

It is equivalent to

```
[[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"some string"]
```

**Here is some more information:**

**alloc** : Class method of NSObject. Returns a new instance of the receiving class.

**init** : Instance method of NSObject. Implemented by subclasses to initialize a new object (the receiver) immediately after memory for it has been allocated.

**new** : Class method of NSObject. Allocates a new instance of the receiving class, sends it an init message, and returns the initialized object.

**release** : Instance method of NSObject delegate. Decrements the receiver’s reference count.

**autorelease** : Instance method of NSObject delegate. Adds the receiver to the current autorelease pool.

**retain**: Instance method of NSObject delegate. Increments the receiver’s reference count.

**copy** : Instance method of NSObject delegate. Returns a new instance that’s a copy of the receiver.

So to conclude we can say that

**alloc** goes with init

**new** = alloc + init

More information could be found https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Initialization/Initialization.html

Comment: It should be pointed out that C++ `new SomeClass()` is actually two operations:  The `new` operation (which can be overridden but rarely is) and the `SomeClass()` constructor.  These correspond quite closely to `alloc` and `init`.

Comment: Note that `new` can be used: `ClassA *object1 = [ClassA new];`